# How do I add (& format) a linear trendline to my ASP (C# Razor) column chart?

Tags: asp.net, xml, razor, charts

I'm fairly new to chart creation in ASP (Razor, C#, XML for formats) and I need to add a trendline to a column chart.

Elsewhere on StackOverflow and other sites, people seem to refer to https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131236/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/111809-1.aspx on this subject, but that's in VB and what looks like Classic .NET.

For the purpose of providing an example of what I want, let's say that I currently have a column chart of a number of columns filled in blue. I want a trendline that's yellow, 4px thick with a 1px black border.

My usings are:

```
@using System;
@using System.Linq;
@using System.Collections;
@using System.Collections.Generic;
@using System.Data;
@using System.Web.Helpers;
```

... but I really don't mind adding new ones &/or deleting some unnecessary ones as advised. My current code for the column chart is:

```
var sqlCommand = "SELECT Date AS AssDate,(Q01+Q02+Q03+Q04+Q05+Q06+Q07+Q08+Q09+Q10+Q11+Q12+Q13+Q14) AS Qtotal FROM Asse WHERE ClientID = @0 ORDER BY AssDate asc";
var AssTotals = db.Query(sqlCommand, ClientID);

var Ass4ClientSumTrendline = new Chart(width: 1200, height: 800, themePath: "~/Admin/Charts/XML/Ass4ClientSumTrendline.xml")
    .AddTitle("All Assessments")
    .AddSeries(
        chartType: "Column",
        name: "Qtotal",
        xValue: AssTotals, 
        xField: "AssDate",
        yValues: AssTotals, 
        yFields: "Qtotal"
        )

    .SetYAxis(
        min: 0,
        max: 70
        )

    .Write();
```

Then my XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Chart BackColor="Cornsilk" 
   BackGradientStyle="TopBottom"
   BackSecondaryColor="Khaki"
   Palette="None"
   AntiAliasing="All"
   BorderStyle="Solid"
   BorderWidth="2"
   PaletteCustomColors="Blue; Pink; Indigo; LightSalmon; Violet; LightYellow; Red; LightGreen; Orange; LightBlue; Yellow; Plum; Green; PaleVioletRed">

  <ChartAreas>    
    <ChartArea Name="Default" _Template_="All" 
           BackColor="White" 
           ShadowColor="#aaaaaa"
           ShadowOffset="2"
           BorderColor="#cccccc" 
           BorderDashStyle="Solid"  
           Position="5,5,90,90">      
      <AxisY LineColor="#cccccc" IsLabelAutoFit="true" IsMarginVisible="true" >        
        <MajorGrid LineColor="#cccccc" />   
        <MajorTickMark LineColor="#aaaaaa" LineWidth="1" LineDashStyle="Solid" /> 
        <MinorGrid LineColor="transparent" />   
        <MinorTickMark LineColor="transparent" LineWidth="1" LineDashStyle="Solid" /> 
        <LabelStyle Font="Verdana, 10 px" />      
      </AxisY>      
      <AxisX LineColor="#cccccc" IsLabelAutoFit="true" IsMarginVisible="true">        
        <MajorGrid LineColor="#cccccc" /> 
        <MajorTickMark LineColor="#666666" />   
        <MinorGrid LineColor="transparent" /> 
        <MinorTickMark LineColor="transparent" />   
        <LabelStyle Font="Verdana, 12 px" />      
      </AxisX>     
     </ChartArea>  
    </ChartAreas>  

    <Legends>    
      <Legend _Template_="All" 
        Alignment="Center" 
        BackColor="Transparent" 
        Docking="Bottom" 
        Font="Helvetica Neue, 12 px" 
        IsTextAutoFit ="False" 
        LegendStyle="Row">   
    </Legend>  
  </Legends> 

  <BorderSkin SkinStyle="Emboss" />
</Chart>
```

Obviously, I need to add a line chart as another .AddSeries, but what I cannot fathom at all is how to format that line. The XML file doesn't seem to have a differentiator ability to format my column chart one way and my line chart another way.

Any help gratefully appreciated.

Comment: This is a pretty vague, multi-part question. If you want to use `DataManipulator` for your trend line, as in the linked article, then you need to use `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting` namespace. If you want to use `System.Web.Helpers` then you need to provide data to the corresponding series. As for the XML theme formatting, yes it can format one series one way and another series another way, but you need to tell exactly what properties you want to format. Chances of getting help increase if you ask specific, well-delimited questions.

Comment: @jstreet - Thanks. Sorry to have been vague - it's sometimes difficult to know when to stop waffling! I've edited my question to provide the extra info you sought ...... I hope.

Comment: So you're not using `DataManipulator`. Do you know how to calculate a trend line? If you don't i suggest researching it online, or using `System.Web.UI` instead, that does it for you. Or you just want to know how to add any two series and apply different formatting to each one using themes? Still not clear what you would consider an answer to your question.

Comment: @jstreet - Thanks again. You're right insofar as there are two issues I need to learn. One is how to add a trendline, the second is how to format the second (and subsequent) series. I had hoped that by asking this question I could kill two birds with one stone. I can certainly do the maths for a trendline, but it seems preferable to let the server take the strain, so I'm going to add to my usings. While I can study the cold MS stuff on DataManipulator at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.datamanipulator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx I tend to .......

Comment: @jstreet - ...... learn much faster by seeing example code.